# usage of ぎりで in this sentence

Tags: て-form, particle-で, particle-って, literature

> どのくらいって、山と田地が少しある**ぎりで**、金なんかまるでないんでしょう

これは夏目漱石の「こころ」の中の一文です。

この「ぎりで」の意味や使い方が分かりません。

---

Googleでも、「あるぎりで」を使う文章は相当に少ないです。

これらは「ぎりで」に関するページですが、

https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A7
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E7%BE%A9%E7%90%86/#je-18610
https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/146708/meaning/m0u/

その中にあるのは、justice(正義)や義務や人との交際などの人に関する解釈ばかりで、この質問の答えになりません。

ですが、「ぎり」で終わる語彙のページも見つけました。

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/en/%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A/m2u/

その中には、「あるかぎり」の英語の例文集があります。

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8B%E9%99%90%E3%82%8A/#je-2005

その「あるぎり」を「あるかぎり」と解釈すれば、この句は理解できるはずです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「どのくらいって、山と田地が少しある**ぎり**で、金なんかまるでないんでしょう。」

この「ぎり」は「きり」とも発音され、副助詞です。「っきり」という形で恐らく既にどこかで見かけているのではないでしょうか。

意味は「だけ」、「かぎり」となります。従って、「少しある**ぎり**」は「少しある**だけ**」というように解釈すれば問題なく理解できると思います。

また、この「ぎり」は、「義理」とは何の関係もない言葉です。発音も違います。

「ぎり」:　「ぎり{HL}」

「義理」:　「ぎり{LH}」